# Using async/await to render information only after db fetching function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

So I have a db fetching function, which is fetching data from firebase, this takes some time when you open the page initially, (data is only finished fetching after 700ms), I am trying to implement a way to let me render the initial information from the DB only after I have all the data fetched, using async/await and promises but I'm not able to implement it correctly.

The project is a little library list, `getFromDB()` gets all the information from firebase onto an array (synching DB with local user), and `render()` merely renders the information to the page into a neat table format

```
// Get all books from the FirebaseDB and synchs with myLibrary Array
function getFromDB() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        myLibrary.length = 0; // clears original stored array to get all books again
        firebaseRef.on("value", function (data) {
            data.forEach((book) => {
                //gets each book from firebase creates new book Object to array in the correct order(chronologically)
                property = book.val();
                let addedBook = new Book(
                    property.title,
                    property.author,
                    property.pages,
                    property.read,
                    book.key
                );
                myLibrary.push(addedBook);
            });
        });
        resolve(true); // resolve
    });
}

async function initialRender() {
    await getFromDB();
    render();
}

initialRender();
```

Still the information is not being rendered, because the `render()` function runs before any information is finished fetching. If I run `render()` on the console manually afterwards, everything renders properly, which means the await or the promise is not working as intended.

Comment: You should resolve inside the firebaseRef.on() so that it waits for it to complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your `resolve(true);` call to the end of your `firebaseRef.on` function.
What is happening now is, as `firebaseRef.on` is an **async** function and `resolve` is written after this function not inside of it, resolve(true); will run as soon as `getFromDB` is run.

```
// Get all books from the FirebaseDB and synchs with myLibrary Array
function getFromDB() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        myLibrary.length = 0; // clears original stored array to get all books again
        firebaseRef.on("value", function (data) {
            data.forEach((book) => {
                //gets each book from firebase creates new book Object to array in the correct order(chronologically)
                property = book.val();
                let addedBook = new Book(
                    property.title,
                    property.author,
                    property.pages,
                    property.read,
                    book.key
                );
                myLibrary.push(addedBook);
            });
            // resolve moved inside
            resolve(true);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        });
         
    });
}

async function initialRender() {
    await getFromDB();
    render();
}
```